# How to keep different copies of gems for different Ruby versions with rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

First I installed fluentd with Ruby 2.6.3.

```
$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /Users/jing/.rbenv/version)
  2.7.5
$ gem
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.gem
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.gem/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-19
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/jing/.gem
     - /Users/jing/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec
     - /Users/jing/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/jing/.tiup/bin
     - /Users/jing/opt/anaconda3/condabin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Users/jing/code/github/zk-code/scripts
     - /Users/jing/tools/apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin/bin
     - /Users/jing/code/github/trace/sky/skywalking-cli/bin
     - /Users/jing/tools/apache-skywalking-apm-bin-es7/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/jing/tools/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
     - /Users/jing/.gem/bin
     - /Users/jing/.cargo/bin
     - /Users/jing/code/github/rtc/depot_tools
     - /Users/jing/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin
     - /Users/jing/tools/apache-skywalking-apm-bin-es7/bin
     - /Users/jing/tools/confluent-6.1.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin
     - /usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin
     - /Users/jing/tools/mongodb-osx-x86_64-4.0.2/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin
     - /Users/jing/tools/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
     - /Users/jing/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
     - /Users/jing/go/bin
     - /Users/jing/.pub-cache/bin
     - /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/fzf/bin
$ gem install fluentd
Successfully installed fluentd-1.14.3
Parsing documentation for fluentd-1.14.3
Done installing documentation for fluentd after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
$ ls ~/.gem/gems -lrt | tail -n1
drwxr-xr-x 28 jing staff 896 Dec  7 10:33 fluentd-1.14.3
$ head -n1 ~/.gem/bin/fluentd
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
```

Then I chose Ruby 2.7.5 with rbenv and installed fluentd again.

```
$ rbenv shell 2.7.5
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.5 (2021-11-24 patchlevel 203) [x86_64-darwin19]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.gem
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jing/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.gem/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jing/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-19
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/jing/.gem
     - /Users/jing/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
     - /Users/jing/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/jing/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec
     - /Users/jing/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/jing/.tiup/bin
     - /Users/jing/opt/anaconda3/condabin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Users/jing/code/github/zk-code/scripts
     - /Users/jing/tools/apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin/bin
     - /Users/jing/code/github/trace/sky/skywalking-cli/bin
     - /Users/jing/tools/apache-skywalking-apm-bin-es7/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/jing/tools/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
     - /Users/jing/.gem/bin
     - /Users/jing/.cargo/bin
     - /Users/jing/code/github/rtc/depot_tools
     - /Users/jing/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin
     - /Users/jing/tools/apache-skywalking-apm-bin-es7/bin
     - /Users/jing/tools/confluent-6.1.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin
     - /usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin
     - /Users/jing/tools/mongodb-osx-x86_64-4.0.2/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin
     - /Users/jing/tools/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
     - /Users/jing/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
     - /Users/jing/go/bin
     - /Users/jing/.pub-cache/bin
     - /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/fzf/binio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/fzf/bin
$ gem install fluentd
Successfully installed fluentd-1.14.3
Parsing documentation for fluentd-1.14.3
Done installing documentation for fluentd after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
$ ls ~/.gem/gems -lrt | tail -n1
drwxr-xr-x 28 jing staff 896 Dec  7 10:37 fluentd-1.14.3
$ head -n1 ~/.gem/bin/fluentd
#!/Users/jing/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/ruby
```

From the above console session, I knew that fluent is re-installed at the same location.

I don't want to have gems from one Ruby version overwrite gems from the other ruby version. Is there a way to keep one gem for one Ruby version separately?

- OS: macOS 10.15.5
- rbenv: 1.2.0

Comment: "From the above console session, I knew that fluent is re-installed at the same location" - where did you see that? Gems for 2.6 are installed under `/ruby/2.6.0` and for 2.7 to `/ruby/2.7.0`, it's not the same folder.

Comment: No, `fluentd` is installed to `./gems/` for Ruby 2.6.3 and Ruby 2.7.5.

Answer (score 2):

By design, you can't.  The project considers this a feature:

`One thing well. rbenv is concerned solely with switching Ruby versions.`

Buuuuut, you can use a plugin to create Gemsets, which you can switch on a per-application basis.

I've not used it, but it appears the `rbenv-gemset` plugin would give you what you're after: https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset.

Once installed, you can create a default gemset in your project's root directory:

`$rbenv gemset init`

Comment: At this point, I'd switch to `rvm` which can _both_ manage Ruby versions, _and_ gemsets (per project/folder).

Comment: Oh no, you're not going to trick me into that particular flamewar :P

(That's a perfectly valid option as well!  I just didn't want to force OP to re-do their versioning system entirely.)

Answer (score 0):

I personally created this shell function for this:

```bash
function switch-ruby-gems() {
    rm -rf "${GEM_HOME}"
    gem install bundler
    bundle install
}
```